# Update a datatable values using another datatable values

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datatables

I have a datatable `dt` that hold some numerical values that have a meaning, the meaning of each value is stored in another datatable `ds`.

For instance a column of `dt` has values from 1 to 9 (sometimes they are written with a .0 at the end, like 1 is written as `1.0` ), the signification of each number is the content at the corresponding index in the other datatable (i.e the meaning of 3 is in `ds.Rows[3][columnName]`).
Both datatables are read from csv.

```
 private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var dt = CleanData(); //removes empty cells after loading csv
            openFileDialog2.ShowDialog();
            var ds = Bind(openFileDialog2.FileName);
            foreach (DataColumn column in ds.Columns)
            {
                if (column.ColumnName == "ANN_ACC") continue; //I don't need to change this
                if (dt.Columns.Contains(column.ColumnName))
                {
                    GetSignif(column, ds, dt);
                }
            }

            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0) dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        }

        private void GetSignif(DataColumn column, DataTable ds, DataTable dt)
        {
            var columnName = column.ColumnName; 
            dt.DefaultView.Sort = columnName;
            dt = dt.DefaultView.ToTable();
            for (var i = 0; i < ds.Rows.Count; i++)
            for (var j = 0; j < dt.Rows.Count; j++)
            {
                var t = i + 1 + ".0";
                var test = dt.Rows[j][columnName].ToString();
                if (test == t || test == (i + 1).ToString())
                {
                    dt.Rows[j][columnName] = ds.Rows[i][columnName];
                }
            }
        }
```

First when I click on a button I get an `openFileDialog` so I can pick the `ds` datatable, then I loop over its columns, and for each column I call a method `GetSignif` that does the change on the `dt` cells.

The code runs without a problem but on the datagridview there is no change on the said values, I am suspecting something in relation with datatables but I am not really sure where the actual problem is.

Edit: You can see that I compared strings in my `if(test ==t ..)` because when I tried to cast to int (or double -> int) I had an error.

Comment: The DGV doesn't automatically get repainted when table is change.  Trick is to set source to null : datagridview1.DataSource = null; datagridview1.DataSource = dt;

Comment: @jdweng I tried that but nothing happens, even though I am pretty sure the DGV does get "repainted" as I've already tried that with another method (`cleanData()`).